# WebView onMessage giving unexpected response

Tags: react-native, webview

I'm trying to get some data out of a WebView and into the RN layer of my app, however the responses I receive from the WebView looks like an event object and I cannot see the string that was sent from the WebView anywhere on the object.

The response looks like the following:

`Proxy { dispatchConfig: Object, _targetInst: Constructor, isDefaultPrevented: function, isPropagationStopped: function, _dispatchListeners: function...}`

Clicking the above object results in weird behaviour, and the structure changes. Once clicked open, the above object looks like:

```
{
    [[Handler]]: Object,
    [[Target]]: SyntheticEvent,
    [[IsRevoked]]: false
}
```

And inside that weird event-looking object above I cannot find the string I've hardcoded to be sent back to RN.

Any ideas?

Here's the code I pass to the WebView:

```
var defer = function (fn, delay) {
  if (!fn || typeof fn !== 'function') return console.log('defer: First argument must be a function.');
  if (!delay) delay = 0;

  return setTimeout(fn, delay);
};

var initBridge = function () {
  try {
    if (!window.postMessage) {
      console.log('Could not initiate WebView bridge');
    }

    defer(function () { window.postMessage('HELLO'); }, 500);
    let sentTest = false
    document.addEventListener('message', function (data) {
      console.log('Received message from RN!');
      console.log(data);
    });

    console.log('WebView bridge successfully initialised');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(window.postMessage);
    console.log('Failed to initiate WebView bridge');
    console.log('Error: ', err);
  }
};

defer(initBridge);
```

And this is my `onMessage` handler:

```
  _onMessage (message) {
    console.log('MESSAGE FROM WEBVIEW: ', message)
    console.log('ARGS: ', arguments)

    this._webView.postMessage('Hello, from RN!')
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you call `message.persist()` on the message you receive from the WebView, then you can find the data under `message.nativeEvent.data`.

Comment: `message.nativeEvent.data` did the trick for me. Is it necessary to call `message.persist()` first?